# "This reminds me of before we were together"

Tags: tense

Recently my girlfriend wrote to me:

> This reminds me of the time before we were together.

Later she corrected herself:

> This reminds me of the time before we **are** together.

Her logic being that we are still together. However, I feel like the latter is incorrect. Even though the more correct way of saying this is probably (as suggested by our American friend):

> This reminds me of the time from before we were together.

– it is still confusing to her why the verb is "were" and not "are". And confusing to me, because I don't know the grammar rules behind these sentences.

How would you explain this to a couple of non-native English speakers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your girlfriend's first sentence is correct.

The phrase "the time before" can only be used to refer to a time in the past. Your girlfriend is talking about a time in the past when the two of you had not yet started a relationship. That period of time is now in the past and did not continue into the present, therefore it must be spoken about in the past tense.

So, you **are** now together, and you **have been** together since your relationship started (presumably), but before then there was a time when you **were** not together. Using "were" in this way does not imply that your relationship only existed in the past, it simply means that the moment in which you came together as a couple is now in the past.

Your girlfriend's second sentence is not grammatically correct. However, I admire her romantic inclinations.

I cannot comment on the sentence from your American friend. Although American English and British English usually follow the same grammar rules, there are times when they do not. I speak British English and that sentence sounded slightly off to me, but it may be perfectly acceptable in the US.

Comment: In American English, when we want to specify the time when something originated or happened, we can use **from** and I think in this respect we're no different from British English:  *That textbook is from my university days* or *That old scar is from my time as a lion tamer.*  And so it's possible to say something like *But this other scar is from before my time as a lion tamer. That injury happened when I was in kindergarten.*  However, the ***the time* from before we were together** is rather awkward because of the pleonasm.

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo  Yes, 'from' can definitely be used in British English in the way you suggest. As the sentence was suggested by an American friend of the OP, I was not sure if the sentence would sound as awkward to American ears as it did to mine. I am glad to know that it does.

Comment: This is a general example of *backshifting* the sentence to a perspective earlier in time.  English speakers often do this to match the subject or context of the sentence. e.g. *"When I was growing up we **lived** the house that we still live in today."*  Or how I get into trouble when talking with my current wife about past events, because I unconsciously refer to my ex-wife as my "wife" because we were married at the time.  e.g. *"My wife and I -- I mean my **ex-wife** and I -- bought this house back in 2001"*

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Great explanation. To be fair, my American friend preferred his another shorter formulation, that I put in the title: ***“This reminds me of before we were together”***.